# Inconsistent accessibility using Delegates

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I'm trying to send a `string` from `form SettingsMenu` to my Main form using a `Delegate`, the structure is as shown below:

Delegate at SettingsMenu form:

```
delegate void ClocknameReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SettingsMenu.ClocknameReceivedEventArgs e);
```

Internal class ClocknameReceivedEventArgs within the SettingsMenu class:

```
public partial class SettingsMenu : Form
{
    internal class ClocknameReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        string _clockname;
        public string Clockname
        {
            get { return _clockname; }
        }

        public ClocknameReceivedEventArgs(string clockname)
        {
            _clockname = clockname;
        }
    }
}
```

And a bit more down in code in `SettingsMenu`:

```
public event ClocknameReceivedEventHandler ClocknameReceived;

// Invoke the Changed event; called whenever list changes
protected void OnClocknameReceived(SettingsMenu.ClocknameReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    ClocknameReceived(this, e);
}
```

I catch the incoming data from `SettingsMenu` on my `Main form` using the following `Event`:

```
_settings.ClocknameReceived += new ClocknameReceivedEventHandler(ClockClocknameReceived);
```

The method on my Main form that actually received the string from SettingsMenu:

```
private void ClockClocknameReceived(object sender, SettingsMenu.ClocknameReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string ClockName;
    ClockName = e.Clockname;
    lblClockname.Text = ClockName;
}
```

Now I get the following errors at the SettingsMenu class:

```
Error   2   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'LivePigeonClient.Forms.SettingsMenu.ClocknameReceivedEventArgs' is less accessible than method 'LivePigeonClient.Forms.SettingsMenu.OnClocknameReceived(LivePigeonClient.Forms.SettingsMenu.ClocknameReceivedEventArgs)'    D:\SVN\sentul\Livepigeonflights\trunk\LivePigeonClientSolution\LivePigeonClient\Forms\SettingsMenu.cs   54  24  LivePigeonClient
```

And

```
Error   1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'LivePigeonClient.Forms.ClocknameReceivedEventHandler' is less accessible than field 'LivePigeonClient.Forms.SettingsMenu.ClocknameReceived' D:\SVN\sentul\Livepigeonflights\trunk\LivePigeonClientSolution\LivePigeonClient\Forms\SettingsMenu.cs   51  52  LivePigeonClient
```

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I needed to use a `public delegate` and a `public class` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your event args are marked as internal, meaning that it is not shared outside of your assemby:

```
internal class ClocknameReceivedEventArgs
```

But then you use it on a method which is maked as protected (which is available outside the assembly):

```
protected void OnClocknameReceived(SettingsMenu.ClocknameReceivedEventArgs e)
```

If the compiler allowed this then how would anyone be supposed to call your method if they can't create the parameter?

To fix, perhaps change them to both be public or both protected, or both internal, depending on how you want this to be used.

Comment: When I change the Internal, to a public class and the protected void to an public void, it will give me plus 13 errors about SuspendLayout. ResumeLayout and 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose' etc.

Comment: @Mobstaa, you don't have anything called SuspendLayout or ResumeLayout in the code sample above.  I think your original question is answered now and you should have a go at fixing this new issue yourself.  Raise a new question if you really get stuck.

Comment: No, that Erorr will I get when I use your method of fixing the problem, so your way isn't the way to doo this

Comment: @Mobstaa, From what you have said sounds like you have writen `using(SuspendLayout x = new SuspendLayout())`.  You can only do `using` on types which implement IDisposable.

Comment: No, that error will occur when I use your way, but that isn't the correct way of fixing this, because I get like dozens of errors that way.

Comment: @Mobstaa, I am suggesting that is likely your code contains more than one bug.  Each bug should be a separate question.  Please do not chain multiple questions together.

Comment: I'am not chaining bug's together, Your way would have created a bug, so it isn't the right way, It is like you tell me: remove a semicolon and then try to resolve all the errors without putting the semicolon back on it's place

Comment: @Mobstaa, Ok well it would be nice if we could test to see if you are right.  How about you delete the `ClocknameReceivedEventArgs` class and the `ClockClocknameReceived` method, and anywhere they are called.  Then you can see if these new errors occur anyway.  If so, then I would suggest that they are a second unrelated bug.  I suspect that did not show up sooner only because your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, just switch the access modifier to public and you should be fine ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using public access specifier to the delegate then, remove it.! It worked great for me.!